# Why i can not run test using run.bat

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

When I am run tests from pycharm all my tests run properly.

```
PS C:\Selenium\vkcom> python -m pytest  -v -m 'sanity'  --html=C:\Selenium\vkcom\vkcom_pytest\reports\report.html C:\Selenium\vkcom\vkcom_pytest\testCases\ --browser Chrome
```

But in case run with 'run.bat'(stored in C:\Selenium\vkcom) I receive this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVnvG.png

My run.bat file :

```
python -m pytest  -v -m 'sanity'  --html=C:\Selenium\vkcom\vkcom_pytest\reports\report.html C:\Selenium\vkcom\vkcom_pytest\testCases\ --browser Chrome
```

pause

Comment: First thing I noticed is that `'sanity'` when given as is is not selecting as per the mark, but when given in double quotes `"sanity"`, it works. Second thing: in your error log, it shows `no module: loguru`. Is it a spelling mistake or is it that you have it with you as is. Please check this and your code might work.

Comment: Thank you very much) Your comment helps me fix the problem. I have just installed loguru from PIP, and it is accepted. Additionally i have changed quotes